# Constraints - inconsistent between design, preview and simulator/device

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode6

Not sure if this is a bug or I am just stupid but begining to start to hate auto layout and constraints. What I see in design view and in the preview is not the same as on the simulator or device.

e.g.

design view

[image: design view]

and preview view

[image: preview view]

and that is exactly how I want it to look... whooooo hooo you would think yet once I run up in the simulator or on my iPad it looks like this

[image: on simulator and device]

note the ihaveadream image seems to be aligned to the top of the view and not the bottom of the blue view as it should be. These are my settings

[image: settings]

So am I an idiot or is this a bug ?

Comment: It's hard to say just by looking at constraint names, but it doesn't look wrong. Have you tried to activate the "clip subviews" option in the UIImageView?

Comment: also try different UIImageView content mode, try aspect fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to depicus selecting the "clip subviews" option solved the problem.

So what happened was that the constraints were correct, the size of the UIImageView was correct as well, but the image was being drawn outside the imageview borders.

This behaviour depends on the content mode of the UIImageView. If you select "scale to size" the image will be scaled exactly to the UIImageView borders; but for some modes, like "center" or "aspect fill" the image can extend past those limits.

So, when you select "clip subviews" for any view, that view will not show any content that falls outside its borders.

Comment: I agree, I was about to give the same answer. It often happens with images that they are drawn outside the image view if they don't fit within bounds. Think about it the next time you have an image that overflows.